# How to adjust plotly marker colors to match ordered categories in R?

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, markers, r-plotly

Using plotly in R, I would like the categories to be different colors (preferably pre-chosen by me) in order of # of songs. Here's what I tried:

```
salesplot <-plot_ly(producersales, type="scatter", x=Producer, y=SalesPerSong, color=c('20+ songs', '11 songs','8-10 songs','5-7 songs', '3-4 songs', '2 songs'), size=SalesPerSong, mode="markers")
## Sample of my data
head(producersales)
               Producer NoOfSongs TotalSales SalesPerSong  SongRange
1             Timbaland        24    3446852       143619  20+ songs
2            Just Blaze        23    3134585       136286  20+ songs
3            Kanye West        20    3338410       166920  20+ songs
4 Jerome "J-Roc" Harmon        11    1165000       105909   11 songs
5          The Neptunes        11    1419877       129080   11 songs
6               No I.D.         9    1437008       159668 8-10 songs
```

The problem is that when I print salesplot, all the markers are in one color (2 songs). Also, if I try using color=SongRange, the legend is not in the order that I need.

Comment: Can you try adding `group = SongRange` and see. Not sure this works for what you want, as I am also new to plotly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
#order factor like you want
producersales$SongRange  <- factor(producersales$SongRange , 
                                   levels = c("8-10songs", "11songs", "20+songs"))

#select colour you want
cols <- c("red", "blue", "black")
#plot
salesplot <- plot_ly(producersales, 
                     type = "scatter", 
                     x = Producer, 
                     y = SalesPerSong, 
                     color = SongRange,
                     colors = cols, 
                     mode = "markers")
salesplot
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was the levels feature but couldn't come up with the name!! Here's what I ended up with:
`producersales$SongRange  <- factor(producersales$SongRange, levels =c("2 songs", "3-4 songs", "5-7 songs", "8-10 songs","11 songs", "20+ songs"))
cols <- c("white", "yellow", "orange", "red", "blue", "green")
salesplot <-plot_ly(producersales, type="scatter", x=Producer, y=SalesPerSong, color=SongRange, colors=cols, mode="markers", size=SalesPerSong)`

I don't know how to make the code separate lines.